# Correct RegEx to avoid infinte loop using RewriteRule to redirect 301

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, http-status-code-301

I am trying to tell my server to redirect the following requests:

```
http://example.es
http://example.es/
http://example.es/es
http://example.es/es/
http://www.example.es
http://www.example.es/
http://www.example.es/es
```

to this page:

```
http://www.example.es/es/
```

In order to do that I have the following in my .htaccess

```
#RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\.?example\.es(/|/es|/es/)?|www\.?example\.es(/|/es)?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.es/es/ [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that it causes infinite redirects since the wanted URL http://www.example.com/es/ also has the HTTP_HOST string within. The thing is I cannot find the accurate regular expression to avoid this problem.

The rest of the .htaccess goes as follows:

```
php_flag register_long_arrays on
php_flag register_globals on
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css javascript application/javascript
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 years"

Header set Connection keep-alive
```

Help is very very appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Apache's rewrite uses PERL regex, so negative-lookaheads are supported. You can use one to avoid matching `http://www.example.com/es/` to itself. Try:

`^(\.?example\.com(/|/es|/es/)?|www\.?example\.com(/|/es(?!/))?)$`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `%{HTTP_HOST}` only matches host name in URL.

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(example\.ws)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^es/)^(.*)$ http://www.%1/es/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry! In order to have a better example I used .com domain but my case is really attached to .es. I changed the original question. With the wrong example all the request where working perfectly except www.example.com/es which redirected to 404 page with the follwing message 'The requested URL /es/es was not found on this server.'. I guess is because of my incorrect example. Besides, I understand the RewriteCond regex but really no clue with the RewriteRule. Why two ^? ^ is for start of the string, right?

Comment: That is actually a negative lookahead which means that execute RewriteRule for all URLs except when URL starts `/es/`

Comment: I made a small edit to adapt to your latest example. Try it now.

Comment: Still have issues with 1) example.es/ redirects to www./es/ 2) example.es/es redirects to http://www./es/es 3) www.example.es/ redirects to www.www./es/ 4) www.example.es/es redirects to www.www./es/es By the way the RewriteCond is correct with the regex ending with 'ws' instead of 'es'? I think is a typo.

Comment: What are the issues, pls provide details. Also copy/paste your complete .htaccess in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(example\.es)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/|/es|/es/)?$ http://www.example.es/es/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Thank you all for your help!!